# Social Icons block Wordpress - how to change the icon image?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to change the icon used in "Social Icons" block in WordPress?

I added a new widgetized area to my footer and put the "Social Icons" block inside.
Now I can add an icon with a facebook link, for example, but unfortunately there is no way to change the default icon.
Is it possible to do this programmatically somehow?

I tried to preview the icon on the page and I see that it is rendered as svg. So it seems to me that the icons should be stored somewhere in WP files, so maybe there is a possibility to replace it somehow?

Comment: There isn't an easy way, but you could do it with block filters or with javascript in a custom plugin/theme.

Comment: @Shoelaced I would rather use filters. Are you able to prop me up in any way?